# When the first word of an initialism is the same as the initialism

Tags: acronyms

Is there a word for an acronym whose first word is identical to the acronym?  There are real-world examples.  However, none come to mind so I will fabricate one here.

> Face
>   Acuity
>   Characteristics
>   Expressions
>
> F.A.C.E.

If there is already  word for it I think it should be called an 'initialistic initialism'.

Or an 'initialised initialism'.

Edit: I am aware I have used' acronym' and 'initialism' interchangeably, my question applies to both.

EDIT: Although "GNU: GNU Not Linux" is a case of this and is known as a recursive acronym. The example I use as well as "IRIS: Iris Recognition Immigration System" are not recursive as the word Iris actually means something. Said another way "GNU: GNU Not Linux" could just as easily be "PNU: PNU Not Linux", the same is not true of IRIS.

Comment: Also *GNU* is recursively for *GNU's Not Unix*. In this case, the expression "recursive acronym" seems indeed to be an established notion, but that may be applicable only because it is *deliberately* so (i.e., the expanded GNU has no meaning by itself).

Comment: Unfortunately the other question's answers also refer to recursive acronyms, which is not the answer to either mine or the other OP's questions.

Comment: "Self-reflexive" is another term that might apply.